# CSP setting kills site in Chrome with ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers

I am adding Security Headers to my website. I am running an Nginx server.

I have used the "Content Security Policy (CSP) Generator" chrome extension to create my CSP settings.

The CSP statement added to nginx ssl.conf are:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';
script-src 'report-sample' 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/.../util.js;
style-src 'report-sample' 'self' https://code.jquery.com https://fonts.googleapis.com;
object-src 'none';
base-uri 'self';
connect-src 'self';
font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;
frame-src 'self';
img-src 'self' data: https://code.jquery.com https://maps.gstatic.com;
manifest-src 'self';
media-src 'self';
report-uri https://???.endpoint.csper.io/;
worker-src 'none';";
```

The only browser these settings seems to work in is Firefox.

When I load the site in Chrome (v77.01) the site does not load. It shows the same result in Edge (Version 83.0.478.54), Safari and Opera.

I see the following info:

> This site can’t be reached The webpage at https:domain.com might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

The ssl certificate is Lets Encrypt and is set to expire in Sept 2020.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Greg J

Answer (score 3):

ok this has been fixed and as usual its really basic, feeling a bit of a douche...

Chrome browser does not like linefeeds in the CSP statement.  once I made the statement a single line it worked perfectly.

Comment: Spent 2+ days on a similar issue. In my case, Angular's static resources like logo and favicon.ico weren't loading in any of the browsers after implementing `http2`. Later I made my CSP statement single-line and it worked in all the browsers.